# Symfony2: FormBuilder for entity - optionsResolver

Tags: php, symfony, entity, formbuilder

I've got 3 entities: Project,User,Module

Module entity got fields:

1. $id
2. $user - Many to One with User entity
3. $project - Many to One with Project entity
4. $modules - ArrayCollection

ModuleController:

```
  $form = $this->createForm(new ModuleType($em), $module, array('user' => $userData, 'project' => $projectData));
```

ModuleType is the problem. I want to build form collection only for specific user (userId) specific project (projectId) with $modules fields.

How should I set setDefaultsOptions to correctly use class Module (to build form) with options user and project?

@Edit
Ok it's almost what I want:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{  
    $transformer = new ModuleToArrayTransformer($this->entityManager);
    $builder->add('modules', 'choice', array(
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'choices' => array(array_keys($options['data'][0]->getModules()))
    ))
    ->addViewTransformer($transformer);
}

public function setObject($object)
{
    $this->object = $object;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{   
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'DevDash\ProjectBundle\Entity\Module',
        'project' => 'DevDash\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project',
        'user' => 'DevDash\ProjectBundle\User',
    ));
}
```

It makes correct form but all boxes are unchecked. Any idea why?

Comment: I can't tell for sure, without seeing your controller, but I don't think you should be passing `user` and `project` to your form type. Instead you should be setting or adding to `Module` in your controller. such as $module->setUser($user); $module->setProject($project); $module->addModules($Modules);

Comment: Modules are generated correctly. User and Project Values are being passed because they are connected with admin panel in which I am setting modules visibility for users (from admin acccount). Also I've got correct values from $options['data'][0]->getModules() - it's an array of boolean values. The question is - the checboxes are not checked when values are set on true?